# react-navigation redux error this.props.navigation.state.index undefined

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

Currently I am working on react native and I am facing issue with react-navigation and redux integration

I am using create-react-native-app for the application

I am getting the following error.

I have seen this `https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/261`, but I am not able to figure out the exact problem in the setup.

Please let me know what else I am missing in the setup

[image: Error Image]

My App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as Expo from "expo";
import { Provider, connect } from 'react-redux';
import store from "./store";
import AppNavigator from './Navigation';
import { addNavigationHelpers } from 'react-navigation';

class Root extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <AppNavigator navigation={addNavigationHelpers({
                dispatch: this.props.dispatch,
                state: this.props.nav,
            })} />
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    nav: state.nav
});

const AppWithNavigationState = connect(mapStateToProps)(Root);

export default class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { isLoading: true};
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.loadFonts();
    }

    async loadFonts() {
        await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
            Roboto_medium: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf")
        });
        this.setState({ isLoading: false });
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return <Expo.AppLoading />;
        } else
            return (
                <Provider store={store}>
                   <AppWithNavigationState/>
                </Provider>
            );

    }
}
```

My Navigation.js

```
import Home from './components/user/Home';
import Auth from "./components/user/Auth";
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
    {
        Auth: { screen: Auth },
        Home: { screen: Home }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "Auth",
        headerMode: "none"
    }
);

const initialState = {
    index: 0,
    routes: [
        { key: 'Auth', routeName: 'Auth' },
    ],
};

export const navReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    const nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
    return nextState || state;
};

export default AppNavigator;
```

I have used it in combine reducers like

```
export default combineReducers({
    nav: navReducer,

});
```

I don't know what I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your Navigation.js as:

```
import Home from './components/user/Home';
import Auth from "./components/user/Auth";
import React from 'react';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
    {
        Auth: { screen: Auth },
        Home: { screen: Home }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: "Auth",
        headerMode: "none"
    }
);

const initialState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(AppNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams('Auth'));

export const navReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    let nextState;
    nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
    return nextState || state;
};

export default AppNavigator;
```

Also, how are you dispatching actions?

PS: I have written an article here for smooth redux and react-navigation integration which might be helpful. **[React-Navigation and Redux](https://hackernoon.com/a-comprehensive-guide-for-integrating-react-navigation-with-redux-including-authentication-flow-cb7b90611adf)**